# update one element of array inside object and return immutable state - redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

```
const InitialState = {
  uploadImages: [],
};
```

On the first update it gets filled with objects and looks like that:

```
const InitialState = {
  uploadImages: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
};
```

i get payload:

```
{arrayIndexToChange: 1, ValutAtIndex: 'e'}
```

Is there anyway i can return immutable state inside my reducer like:

```
return [...state, //someway to update value at index in array ]
```

Comment: also see:https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array - `return state.map((x, i) => i === action.payload.arrayIndexToChange ? action.payload.ValueAtIndex : x);`